# How to limit incoming web access to a particular network interface?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have an apache running in CentOS which comes with two network cards, such that the web server can be access via intranet and internet:

- http://www.example.com/index.php
- http://192.168.1.101/index.php

For a particular folder "`upload`", i.e.:

- http://www.example.com/upload/form.php
- http://192.168.1.101/upload/form.php

how can I limit traffic only allow from 192.168.x.x network but deny from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You need some access control directives:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
```

You can put these in your <Directory /upload> configuration or in a file named .htaccess in your "upload" folder.

More information on: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html